# How to add facebook like slidingmenu in only 1 screen?

Tags: iphone, slidingmenu

I want to add facebook like left sliding menu in only one screen in my application.
I found lots of solutions on github but those all adds menu in all screen. I want it in just one screen.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MFSlideMenu. You can set panMode to `MFSideMenuPanModeNone` disable slide in required viewController. See [this](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

Comment: should we done it without applying RootViewController...Like self.window.rootviewcontroller=mainviewcontroller;  here mainviewcontroller is MFSideMenuContainerViewController ....

Answer (score 0):

After using [MFSideView](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu)

Indise SideMenuViewController.m in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method from tableview delegate
allocate your view controller using

```
    <CLASS_NAME> *obj = [[[<CLASS_NAME> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<XIB_NAME>" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

Bind this into array

```
NSArray <ARR_NAME> = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:obj,nil] autorelease];
```

refernce this into navigation controller

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = self.menuContainerViewController.centerViewController;

[navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[secArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;

[self.menuContainerViewController setMenuState:MFSideMenuStateClosed];
```

This is the entire code for your problem !!

Enjoy Programming !!